# Access denied finding property "ro.serialno"

Tags: php, android, json, android-studio

I've been trying to create a json format to display it on the android app so I can use it on my ewallet project but I've been getting error Access denied finding property "ro.serialno" or " org.json.JSONException: End of input at character "

I think the main reason of the connection is the error of Access denied, also before the Run debugging I've been seein a lots of denied permissions.

This is my code on the login for the e-wallet:

```
package RAMS.e_wallet;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
private static EditText etNumber, etPassword;
private static String phone = null;
private static final String password = null;
private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.218/login1/login/login.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    etNumber = findViewById(R.id.username);
    etPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
}
public void backToMenu (View v){
    phone = etNumber.getText().toString().trim();
    if(!phone.equals("")){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {


                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, jsonObject.getString("success"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "e"+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "err"+error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }){
            @NotNull
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put("phone_number", phone);
                return data;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fields cannot be empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}



public void switchRegister (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Register.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    }

}
```

here's my dependencies on the gradle

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.3'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0'
testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.9.0'

}
```

my PHP code for the login

```
    <?php

    class Reply{

   function procced(){

       if(isset($_POST['phone']))
       {
       require_once "conn.php";
       require_once "validate.php";
       $phone = var_dump($_POST['phone']);
       $sql = "select * from users where phone_number= '$phone'";
       $result = $conn->query($sql);


         if($result->num_rows > 0)
           {
            session_start();
            $data=["response"=>"success"];
            return json_encode($data);
           }
       
         else{
           $data=["response"=>"error"];
           return json_encode($data);
         }
     }

     $data=["response"=>"error"];
           return json_encode($data);
    }
  }

?>
```

and the Json format that i've been trying :

```
package com.example.json;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mTextview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTextview = findViewById(R.id.textviewresult);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.218/jsonlogin/json.php";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();


    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    String myResponse = response.body().toString();

                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mTextview.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });

                }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

the json code is in a different activity because i'm trying to display numerous data for a textview

also, all of the codes have the internet permission on their manifests